# python api common response format

Tags: python, api, response

I have a dictionary which I used to return my response in an API. 
It is formatted as this:

```
response_data = {
        'url': '',
        'status': '',
        'data': ''
}
```

when I update it inside my function I have to declare it in every function then update a data individually like:

```
response_data ['url'] = url
response_data ['status'] = status
response_data ['data'] = data
```

then return it as:

```
return response_data
```

Is there a way to not initiate it in every function I made, like a class or function which I can just easily pass the data or edit the data to be passed.

Have tried this, but you have to manually edit the data like what I was doing.

```
class Response:
    response_data = {
            'url': '',
            'status': '',
            'data': ''
    }

    def set_message(self, key, value):

        try:

            self.response_data[key] = value
        except Exception as e:
            raise Exception(e)

response = Response()
response.set_message('success', success)
```

Comment: You can try global variables

Comment: Care to share the code with whatever you have tried till now?

Comment: @DineshKumar see edited question

Comment: @Keibry May I know where are returning your response_data dictionary? Also when you say "Is there a way to not initiate it in every function I made" do you mean the response_data should be available across in all the methods? pls correct me if my understanding is wrong

Comment: @DineshKumar 
1st quesiton: In my api calls, it's how I return my response when an api is being accessed. 2nd question: Yes.

Comment: @Keibry Did u try the dictionary's setdefault(key,None) method to update the values?. Since this is a class variable you can always access it across different methods by Response.response_data unless you have a reason to have it as a instance variable.